# How can I authenticate via Firebase Google Auth on localhost

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, emberfire

I'm building a site with emberfire and using firebase. Everything seems to be set up fine regarding credentials, and I can read/write to the firebase database while developing locally, but every time I try to authenticate via the Google Popup it pops up fine with my Google accounts listed, and when I select my account it errors with this error object:

`code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."`

I assume I'm simply missing a setting somewhere but for the life of me I cannot find it. Here's the code to get the popup and response:

```
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    this.firebaseApp.auth().then(auth => {
      /* Firebase SDK calls */
      auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
```

Comment: The configuration works fine from jsfiddle, and I am sure that localhost is set in my authorized domains.

Answer (score 0):

I am using EmberJS with emberfire.

In my environment I had `host: 'api'`, and when removing that authentication works, so it must be one of the adapters that is used.